# Regex - returning overlapping matches

Tags: regex, overlap

How do I change this regular expression:

```
(`)([^`]+)`|(\*)([^*]+)\*
```

To give an output like this:

```
` | hel*low
* | low`orld
* | hello
` | world
```

When passed:

```
"`hel*low`orld* *hello* `world`"
```

http://regex101.com/r/aV5bG0

Comment: Your best bet is probably to run two, one for `\`` and one for `*`. What language are you working in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?=([`*])((?>[^`*\W]++|(?!\1)[`*])+)\1)
```

or this pattern:

```
(?=([`*])((?:[^`*\W]+|(?!\1)[`*])+)\1)
```